# Can a piezoelectric material only vibrate at one frequency?

Tags: waves, crystals, piezoelectric

Given a material X with piezoelectric properties which is used in a ultrasonic transducer, what determines the working frequency of said transducer?

If hypothetically such a transducer is specified to have two standard frequencies; 820 KHz, and 2.5 MHz, could this mean that any frequency in-between can be used?

If not, what would happen if a generated signal with a different frequency, let's say 1.5 MHz, was connected to the transducer?

Comment: Frequency comes from the driving voltage.  It's easy to change the frequency.

Comment: So a single transducer might be operated at different frequencies? what happens if it is not operated at its 'standard frequencies'?

Comment: See, perhaps,  http://www.pi-usa.us/products/Active_Optics_Steering_Mirrors/index.php#MATT    and  https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/EquipmentTrans/characteristicspt.htm  for some info.

Answer (score 0):

Anything will vibrate at any frequency, given enough power. With a crystal there is a natural resonance. In simple sonar transducers the ping rate of excitation is far less than the natural resonance. This is so the receiver can have a period to detect the echo with the same crystal. More complex approaches use Doppler and interference and can have multiple crystals, but the concept is the same.

crystals like anything else have overtones and 'spurs'. power mismatch happens when driving frequencies are not matched with the crystal.